# How to create a nested filter with lodash

Tags: javascript, json, filter, lodash

I have the following nested JSON data structure. Each node can have any number of children and the data can be any number of nodes deep.

```
[{
    id : "a",
    path : "a"
}, {
    id : "b",
    path : "b"
}, {
    id : "c",
    path : "c",
    children: [{
        id : "a",
        path : "c/a"
    }, {
        id : "b",
        path : "c/b",
        children: [{
            id : "a",
            path : "c/b/a"
        }, {
            id : "b",
            path : "c/b/b"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I need to create a function in lodash (v3.10.1) which returns a nested JSON object of matching paths, and any parent objects.
For example, if I was to search on "b" the filter should return the following:

```
[{
    id : "b",
    path : "b"
}, {
    id : "c",
    path : "c",
    children: [{
        id : "b",
        path : "c/b",
        children: [{
            id : "a",
            path : "c/b/a"
        }, {
            id : "b",
            path : "c/b/b"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

My initial attempt was like this but it did work:

```
const filterTree = (filter, list) => {
    return _.filter(list, (item) => {
        if (item.path) {
            return _.includes(item.path.toLowerCase(), filter.toLowerCase());
        } else if (item.children) {
            return !_.isEmpty(filterTree(filter, item.children));
        }
    });
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41175686/1988157 it can be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that `if (item.path)` is always `true`, so the recursive calls never happen.

In order to get your desired result, you will have to update `item.children` after filtering in the recursive cases, because `_.filter` will not mutate the array that you pass to it. If you don't want the input to be mutated, use `_.cloneDeep` to make a copy first.

```js
const data = [{"id":"a","path":"a"},{"id":"b","path":"b"},{"id":"c","path":"c","children":[{"id":"a","path":"c/a"},{"id":"b","path":"c/b","children":[{"id":"a","path":"c/b/a"},{"id":"b","path":"c/b/b"}]}]}];

const filterTree = (filter, list) => {
  return _.filter(list, (item) => {
    if (_.includes(_.toLower(item.path), _.toLower(filter))) {
      return true;
    } else if (item.children) {
      item.children = filterTree(filter, item.children);
      return !_.isEmpty(item.children);
    }
  });
};

console.log(filterTree('b', data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @4castle, you're a star!