# Finding nested object in a collection with Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, lodash, es5-compatiblity

```
var collection = {
  'key1': [
    { 'uuid': '123', 'a': 'a' },
    { 'uuid': '456', 'b': 'b',
      'randomKeyValue': [
        { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
      ]
    }
  ],
  'key2': [
    { 'uuid': '890', 'c': 'c' }
  ]
}
```

Using `_.find(collection, { 'uuid': '349' })` will return undefined.

How to find the hash that has `uuid == 349`?

The expected return of the find is: `{ 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }`

Must be written with ES5 standards and must use Lodash.

Comment: Is lodash a strict requirement here or can you use vanilla js as well?

Comment: @briosheje yes, lodash is required

Comment: similar question solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175686/1988157

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly straightforward using plain js

```js
var collection = {
    'key1': [
        { 'uuid': '123', 'a': 'a' },
        { 'uuid': '456', 'b': 'b' }
    ],
    'key2': [
        { 'uuid': '890', 'c': 'c' },
        { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
    ]
}

const res = Object.values(collection).flat().find(({uuid}) => uuid === '349');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: (crispy bacon?), how would you write this more dynamically, if there were multiple levels of nesting?

Comment: crispy bacon. That's right! :D Can you share some demo data?

Answer (score 1):

```
_.filter(_.flatMap(collection), function(o) { return o.uuid == '349' });
```

Comment: If there are multiple entries with the same `uuid`, `_.filter` will return them all matching, `_.find` will return only the first one it found.

Comment: If i only need the first: `_.find(_.flatMap(collection), { uuid: '349' });`